# ERR EXEC without MULTI - Vertx-Redis 3.7.0

Tags: vert.x

I'm trying to execute `multi` with `vertx-redis-client`, version is `3.7.0`. The documentation is very bad that I'm not even sure how to use `multi`. I somehow tried the following code. The output is very inconsistent. Sometime it executes normally and sometimes throws the error saying `ERR EXEC without MULTI`

Code:

```
        Map<String,String> keyFields =  new HashMap<>();
        keyFields.put("{test}:t1", "f1");
        keyFields.put("{test}:t2", "f2");
        redisAPI.multi(ar1 -> {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: keyFields.entrySet()) {
                redisAPI.hget(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), ar2 -> {
                    if ("QUEUED".equals(ar2.result().toString())) {
                        System.out.println("its queued");
                        redisAPI.exec(execEvent -> { 
                            System.out.println(execEvent);
                            System.out.println("Result is: "+ execEvent.result());
                        });
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Result is: "+ ar2.result());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Output with error:

```
its queued
Future{cause=ERR EXEC without MULTI}
Result is: null
its queued
Future{cause=ERR EXEC without MULTI}
Result is: null
```

Without error:

```
Result is: v2
Result is: v1
```

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small bug with this code. Lets look at what it's happening in terms of redis commands:

```
MULTI // Line 4
HGET "{test}:t1", "f1" // Line 6 (inside loop)
EXEC // Line 9 (because the response is immediate the callback gets called here)
HGET "{test}:t2", "f2" // Line 6 (second iteration of the loop)
EXEC // Line 9 Fail since there's no multi
```

Even if thing would be a bit delayed there would be a bug:

```
MULTI // Line 4
HGET "{test}:t1", "f1" // Line 6 (inside loop)
HGET "{test}:t2", "f2" // Line 6 (second iteration of the loop)
EXEC // Line 9
EXEC // Line 9 Fail since there's no multi
```

Finally the expected result does not match the test, as you're calling `HGET` without having populated the initial hash (perhaps this was omitted to keep the example simpler).

I'd recommend a different approach:

```
redis.batch(Arrays.asList(
  cmd(MULTI),
  cmd(HGET).arg("{test}:t1").arg("f1"),
  cmd(HGET).arg("{test}:t2").arg("f2");
  cmd(EXEC)
), batch -> {
  // At this moment you have all responses
});
```

This approach avoids you to fight asynchronous loops. And indeed is not documented as it should.

Comment: I tried the batch. I have all the keys in same slot. Still geting the error: `Future{cause=RedisClusterClient does not handle batching commands with keys across different slots. TODO: Split the command into slots and then batch.}`

Comment: Distributed transactions are not supported by the redis client, you should connect to the node you know holds all the keys and run the transaction there.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, When could we expect the support for `batch` in cluster mode

Comment: Probably we need to add a check for this case, all commands are on the same slot or require no specific slot. But real distributed transaction is something out of the scope due to its complexity.

Comment: @rmn.nish This https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/pull/156 implements this and will be on 4.0